# WPF: Specify a language for built-in Command labels

Tags: wpf, localization, menu, command

I'm using the built-in `ApplicationCommands` to create a menu:

```
<Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
    <MenuItem Header="_Datei">
        <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.New" />
        <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Open" />
        <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Save" />
        <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.SaveAs" />
        <Separator />
        <MenuItem Header="Been_den" Command="{StaticResource SchliessenCommand}" />
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

The text displayed by the `ApplicationCommands` differs depending on the system language: Running on an English Windows 7, `ApplicationCommands.New` displays as "New", whereas it displays as "Neu" on a German Windows 7.

Since the rest of the application is not localized, I want the application commands to always display in German language. Is there a way to do that *without* manually setting the `Header` of each MenuItem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the application isn't localized, you can try to always set the language to german; that is, `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture`, which is normally inherited from the OS (set it in application startup or something like that, before any windows are opened).

Comment: Nice idea. Unfortunatly, Changing `CurrentUICulture` for the UI thread did not make a difference.

Comment: +1. I just found this thread, which seems to imply that your approach is correct, but on an English Windows, the satellite assemblies for German are just not installed: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/9d3f9534-4a10-4860-90b5-d2ea5c967fca

Answer (score 0):

You should use bindings and manipulate your commands as bind objects ([RelayCommands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090051)) to avoid the hardcoding of the headers of your different commands.

Comment: Please elaborate: How will that change the behaviour of the built-in ApplicationCommands?